# Two array list - Merge to create values

Tags: vb.net

I just can't get my head around doing this. . .

I am targeting the 2.0 .net framework using visual studio 2017 and using visual basic.

I have two list ARRAYS one being string and the other single.

```
Dim Products As New List(Of String)

Dim Quantity As New List(Of Single)
```

The List's has the following data:-

```
Products(0)="1-1/xs":Quantity(0)=2

Products(1)="1-1/s" :Quantity(1)=3

Products(2)="1-1/m" :Quantity(2)=5

Products(3)="1-1/xs":Quantity(3)=7

Products(4)="1-1/m" :Quantity(4)=8
```

I need to know how do I programically get this result:-

```
Products(0)="1-1/xs":Quantity(0)=9

Products(1)="1-1/s" :Quantity(1)=3

Products(2)="1-1/m" :Quantity(2)=13
```

The result is taking all the products; then looking at the products that has duplicates (remove the duplicate item) and add that items quantity to the Quantity list.

Will someone please able to assist me. .

Comment: Do you need to keep these in two separate arrays?   
I would recommend storing the items in a Dictionary(string,single) object with the key being your product name, and the value being your quantity.   Keys are unique and you can easily lookup the product to see if it exists and update your quantity.

Comment: I have not used dictionary before ! could you give me a snippet of code that would show me how it could be used in my scenario. I will in the mean time look up the dictionary object . . . I don't really have to keep them in two seperate arrays ; I did that because i was using LIST.

Comment: Thanks Bob K, the dictionary object worked just fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of populating the dictionary.
You would loop through your data, populate the dictionary with new objects if they did not exist, and increment the quantity when it does exist.

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    ' Add two keys.
    dictionary.Add("1-1/xs", 2)
    dictionary.Add("1-1/s", 1)

    ' See if this key exists.
    If dictionary.ContainsKey("1-1/xs") Then
        ' Write value of the key.
        Dim num As Integer = dictionary.Item("1-1/xs")
        Console.WriteLine(num)
        ' Or add quantity to it
        dictionary.Item("1-1/xs") = dictionary.Item("1-1/xs") + 1
    End If
```

Dictionaries can contain any object.  So you may be inclined to rethink what you are storing.  You could for example store a Product class with several properties like color, size, etc and use the Product's ID (sku for  example) as the key in the dictionary.

for Example:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Product)  'where Product is a class.


Public Class Product
  Public Size as String
  Public Color as String
  Public Id as String
  'etc, etc
End Class
```